# How to get amount and pair address from signed tx on Uniswap v3

Tags: calldata, uniswapv3

I'm learning to understand call data and trying to decode information what swap should happen from signed tx, which is done on Uniswap V3. It means ideally find out Uniswap pair address and amount in and out. I'm testing it on Goerli. This is what I do.

1. I go to Uniswap V3 Goerli and try some swap.
2. I have localhost as RPC URL in Metamask, so I catch call data on my BE and now I want to decode it to understand it.
3. I am able to decode transaction and transaction has payload.
4. This payload can look like this:

```
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
```

And this calldata are sent to the Uniswap Universal Router - 0x4648a43b2c14da09fdf82b161150d3f634f40491.

When you check selector (0x3593564c) and contract's functions, it is easy to figure out that function "execute(bytes calldata commands, bytes[] calldata inputs, uint256 deadline)" is called.

But then it starts to hard to understand. This is how I split it up:

```
//selector
0x3593564c
// offset where data will start
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
// offset where data will start
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
// deadline
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063d03140 -- timestamp 

// start of first parameter
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 --lenght of lenght 1
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 - 00 parameter, that means it is V3_SWAP_EXACT_IN

// start of the second element
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 --lenght of array 1
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 --lenght of byte is 32
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100 -- HERE 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```

And from "HERE" I dont understand how to get address of pair (or token0 and token1 addresses would be enough) where will be swap and amount int amount out from these data. Anyone can help how it can be done? Thank you very much.

Comment: Universal Router is the new stuff Uniswap has released recently. You don't need it. In v3 it is no longer called Pair, it is called Pool. You can get the Pool address by calling `getPool` function

Comment: Go to Etherscan, locate Uniswap v3 factory address, click "Read Contract" button, scroll to "getPool", input the addresses of your tokens, and the fee. The fee is usually 500. Click "Query" button, that's it

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer. I know how to get the pool manually via Etherscan. What I am curios here how to get there from call data.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, what you want is to decode trade information from the input. the `HERE` is the length of the remaining parameters. 100 in hex is 256. The remaining data is 256 bytes long (i.e. each parameter is of length 32 and you have left 8 of them)

Comment: That second parameter is "bytes[]" and it should start on line 7. First 32 bytes are size of array, it is 1 and then in next 32 bytes should be lenght of the byte and it is 20 hex - 32 bytes. How it is possible that in next 32 bytes are lenght? What I have wrong in my understanding? I would expect there the 32 bytes long value itselft.

Comment: By line 7 I mean line after "// start of the second element".